# Centering the navbar links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried most of the approach, but I'm unable to center align the links in my navbar.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 30px 20px !important;
}

a {
  /* color: #fff !important;*/
  font-family: 'Caesar Dressing';
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 30px !important;
}

a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

[this is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbh2F.png)

But I want all the 4 links to be vertically centered on the screen

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap3

Comment: you can check my new answer which is relatively close to your answer.

Comment: @addy I have already tried that, it's not working

Comment: then maybe another CSS affect your navbar check this by inspector tools maybe you find better option to do it.

Comment: thanks @addy...it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for :

```
 .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
```

*for center align the whole inner link*

Comment: not working, I have attached a snapshot, please take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `text-align` property on `li` of `navbar` like this

```
.navbar-nav > li 
{
text-align :center;
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 30px 20px !important;
}

a {
  /* color: #fff !important;*/
  font-family: 'Caesar Dressing';
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 30px !important;
}

a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li 
{
  text-align :center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar-nav > li > a
{
  text-align :center;
}
```

add thin to your css.

Comment: this will center align the lint text within the link's area, but what I want is to horizontally center the navbar links(100%width of navbar, and then center align all the links)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS,

```
 .navbar-nav{
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
 .navbar-nav > li{
   margin: 0 5px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top; 
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > a {
   margin: 5px 0;
   background-color: #ccc;
 }
```

https://jsbin.com/qovilonagu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: what you suggested will center the link's text, but I want to horizontally center the navbar links(100%width of navbar, and then center align all the links)

Comment: for center align of tab you can use .navbar-nav { margin:auto; }

Comment: are you looking for something like this ?
https://jsbin.com/gipuporiso/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: No, again this is centering the link's text in the link's specified area, but not centering all the links in the center of navbar itself

Comment: Are you referring that the `navbar-nav` will be centered ?

Comment: @Amit you can refer my edited answer. I understood what you were looking for. Thank you for the screenshot.

Comment: @Amit glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add text-center class with the container-fluid

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```